# PhoneGap - exec() call to unknown plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been trying to use [Phonegap Image Resizer](https://github.com/raananw/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer) plugin in my project, but I couldn't make it work.

The error log returns:
`D/PluginManager(13992): exec() call to unknown plugin: com.webXells.imageResizer`

I've moved all the necessary things into my project folder. Here's the structure:

```
/assets
 /js
  cordova.js
  imageresize.js
 /www
  index.html
  upload.html
/src
 /com
  /webXells
   /ImageResizer
     ImageResizerPlugin.java
```

I've also include the plugin into `config.xml` in `/res/xml`:

```
<feature name="imageResizer">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.webXells.imageResizer.ImageResizePlugin"/>
</feature>
```

In `upload.html` I've included the plugin like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/imageresize.js"></script>
```

And this is how I call a method to use it:

```
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      window.imageResizer.resizeImage(
        function(data) { 
          var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
          smallImage.style.display = 'block';
          image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 
          //image.src = imageData; 
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log("Error : \r\n" + error);
        },
        imageData,
        0.5,
        0.5,
        {
          imageDataType:ImageResizer.IMAGE_DATA_TYPE_BASE64,
          resizeType:ImageResizer.RESIZE_TYPE_FACTOR,
          format:'jpg'
        }
      );
}
```

So, inside the `imageresize.js` the method that I wanna use looks like this. You can refer to the above link if necessary:

```
ImageResizer.prototype.resizeImage = function(success, fail, imageData, width,
        height, options) {
    if (!options) {
        options = {}
    }
    var params = {
        data : imageData,
        width : width,
        height : height,
        format : options.format,
        imageDataType : options.imageType,
        resizeType : options.resizeType,
        quality : options.quality ? options.quality : 70
    };

    return cordova.exec(success,fail,"com.webXells.imageResizer","resizeImage",[params]);
}
```

In the above code, I noticed that `com.webXells.imageResizer` didn't called as reported in the logcat. What confuses me is the fact that I have included it in `config.xml` and moved the java file in `src` folder. Why can't it be called even though I have done all the stuff that is necessary?

Some researches I made, says to declare the plugin in `plugin.xml`, but I don't have the file inside `res/xml`. So, I put it in `config.xml` instead.
[Other](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using) recommend to use `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.example" />` but Eclipse found error to this.

So, how do I get around this? Have I called the method in HTML correctly? Or there is something I missed?

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: Also, in your directory tree it looks like the file is: `/src/com/webXells/ImageResizer/ImageResizerPlugin.java` but the value that you have in `config.xml` is with a lower case 'i': `value="com.webXells.imageResizer.ImageResizePlugin` - copy/paste error?

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thanks. It was a typing error. Now another problem appears. Do you have any idea what `file:///android_asset/js/cordova.js: Line 982 : processMessage failed: Stack: Error: Error calling method on NPObject.` means? I've googled around haven't returned any results yet.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. I'm not sure what that error message means; I have encountered NPObject errors before and it's always hard to google. I *think* NPObject is something to do with a native browser event, before when I have seen this it was doing things like sending a keyDown event or something. Maybe you should create a new question and include the offending code.

Answer (score 1):

As of cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6, the res/xml/config.xml is overwritten upon build. try adding the feature tag to the config.xml in your app root dir. worked for me.

Comment: For me changing `<feature name="Plugin">` to  `<gap:feature name="Plugin">` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the the plugin using CLI like "corodova add plugin xyz" or manually adding the plugin to eclipse project ?
If u are adding the plugin manually then when run "cordova run android/ios" the config.xml in res folder is overridden so the above error.
I found an hack/solution for this as i was using revmob plugin which is not CLI based we have to add the plugin maually.In ur project/plugins folder there is android.json u have to add feature tag in that so config.xml get rewrited  while running the app through CLI

HERE IS THE SAMPLE

```
"config_munge": {
 "res/xml/config.xml": {
        "/*": {
            "<feature name=\"Device\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.device.Device\" /></feature>": 1,
            "<feature name=\"RevMobPlugin\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"com.revmob.cordova.RevMobPlugin\" /></feature>": 0
        }
    }
},
```

JUST TRY